# Mostrar en Log la data con la cual se esta llenando un cursor en android

Tags: android, sqlite3

Tengo un cursor que los estoy llenando desde la base de datos SQLite, pero aparentemente esta vació, quiero mostrarlo en consola mediante un log.

```
cursor=db.obtenerSaldoClienteFavor(idClienteA);
```

este es mi cursor, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Primero tienes que llamar a `cursor.moveToFirst()`.
- Luego `Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor))`

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar esto necesitas saber los nombres de los campos y el tipo de dato de los campos que obtiene tu consulta ya que en base a esto determinaras que método usaras para obtener el valor, por ejemplo:

> [getString (int columnIndex)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor) Devuelve el valor de la columna solicitada
>   como una cadena.
>
> [getInt (int columnIndex)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor) Devuelve el valor de la columna solicitada
>   como un int.
>
> [getLong (int columnIndex)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor) Devuelve el valor de la columna solicitada
>   como un largo.
>
> [getDouble (int columnIndex)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor) Devuelve el valor de la columna solicitada
>   como doble.
>
> [getBlob (int columnIndex)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor) Devuelve el valor de la columna solicitada
>   como una matriz de bytes.

y mediante un bucle usando `while`, puedes obtener los valores usando el método **[getColumnIndex()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String))** que es donde especificarías el nombre del campo.

---

Suponiendo que tu consulta obtiene los campos `idCliente` y `nombre`, este sería una ejemplo:

```
Cursor cursor  = db.obtenerSaldoClienteFavor(idClienteA);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Log.i("Dato cursor", "idCliente " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("idCliente")) + " nombre: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nombre")));
}
c.close();
```

***Es muy importante cerrar el cursor mediante el método `close()` al terminar de obtener los datos.**

---

### Obtener el numero de elementos en el cursor

Para obtener el numero de elementos contenidos en tu cursor puedes usar el método [**getCount()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount())

Ejemplo:

```
Cursor cursor  = db.obtenerSaldoClienteFavor(idClienteA);
Log.i("Datos cursor", "Número de elementos: " + cursor.getCount(); 
...
...
```